# How to edit /etc/sudoers to allow a user to run specific shell scripts?

Tags: php, security, permissions, sudo

I have a few scripts in a directory which I need `www-data` to run (from PHP) with root permissions.  It seems like

```
CMND_ALIAS= /path/to/script, /bin/sh

www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: CMND_ALIAS
```

gives www-data a little much freedom, since couldn't it execute any script using `/bin/sh` at that point?  Yet, if I take `/bin/sh` off the alias, the scripts don't work.  Does anyone know the proper way to specifically allow root access to ONLY a few scripts in `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: Are you sure you need your web server to run them as root, rather than giving www-data access to whatever files you need modified?

Comment: You could use a simple C wrapper which executes the shell scripts on your behalf, and grant sudo access to the wrapper. but that leads to other problems.

Comment: It seems like giving www-data access to the files is worse in this case, as if it were compromised, I don't want www-data to be able to edit those files.  If it can only sudo certain scripts to do what it needs to do, then if someone gained control of it, they couldn't do anything interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for Apache's "suexec"

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/suexec.html